# Faster in javascript to check xy coordinates of multiple divs or parse a stored array of the coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

I am making a js function that:
 - creates a new div
 - compares the xy coordinates of that newly-created div against others that already exist
 - diagonally bumps the new div if its default coordinates are already occupied by an existing div

So, if I click a button and make a new div (a draggable box), I just want to do a quick scan of the coordinates of all boxes that are already on the page, and if I find a box that already has the coordinates of the new box that is being placed on the page, bump that new box down and to the left a bit.  I'll probably also put that in a loop, in case the initial bump drops it exactly onto yet another box.

I'm using jquery too, if that hones a response.  I already know how to do the coding, my question is the approach.

I'm wondering which would be processed faster to make the comparison:

- having all existing div coordinate pairs already stored in a js array (which updates when any the divs/boxes are dragged, actually using the next approach pre-emptively) and just run a function checking if the index exists

  -- or --
- a js function that loops through all the box divs (they all have a common css class), checking all existing divs coordinates directly on the page (vs. looking for them stored in an array)

I don't need to store the coordinates in an array for any other reason, so that would be unnecessary if it wouldn't be the preferable approach in the first place.  Storing the coordinates in the array would basically be doing the same process as the latter approach, but I'm curious if javascript poking through that array would be faster than the process of checking the coordinates in the first place.

I'm guessing that the performance difference would not be especially significant, but I am curious which approach is wiser.

Comment: Why not just test it on jsperf.com?

Comment: cool, i wasn't aware of this.  thank you.  however, i'm afraid it would be difficult to condense this project into this test environment, i'm working with several libraries and php processes and stuff that factor in to the div manipulation.  still, this would be a good way to do the test if i can shave it down to the essentials.

Comment: create a collection of existing divs and sort it by their coordinates. the new div will go to the end. or do I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: There are two answers to "which is faster" questions: 1) It doesn't matter; you're prematurely optimizing; or 2) Test it.

Comment: it isn't as much a problem as it is just a request for guidance.  in both approaches, there is a function that loops through and grabs the DOM coordinates of every existing div (box), in order to bump the newly-created box when a box already exists in that xy coordinate spot.  my question is whether it is faster to just do that coordinate check to arrive at the bump comparison, or to have those coordinates stored in an array first, before I even want to make a new box, as perhaps parsing the array is faster when doing the actual "bump" of the new box than checking the coordinates freshly.

Comment: yes, i do suffer from premature optimization :)

Comment: coding questions without code don't tend to get very far - show us something and we can help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is clear. When you only want to check for occupied divs then your first method is fastest but when you want to check for closest pair it's a well know computional problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem.

Edit: Why not sort the dives and add the new div to the end?

Comment: Hi I updated my question, hopefully it is more clear.  I'm just curious of the speed between the approaches, both will work fine and I know how to write the code for either.  Thanks for that link, though --  I would love to actually develop an algorithm to intelligently move and place ALL of the boxes on the page, but that is beyond the scope of this project.

Comment: @dshuta: IMO it isn't very clear. What do you mean with checking directly? Can you touch the divs?

Comment: i expanded the question some more.  yeah, all the divs are draggable boxes, but by "checking directly" i meant to say a function that loops through and checks all xy coords of existing divs (boxes).  my curiosity is whether it is faster to check those DOM coordinates, or look for them stored in an array (which would already be populated by these same DOM coordinates from a pre-emptive function).

Comment: Why not sort the divs and add the new div to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You might find elementFromPoint useful for this purpose

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint

It only gives you the front most element at a given point. In your case, this might work. Just make sure you check **before** placing the new div in the DOM tree.

I am not sure if this works on absolute positioned elements, and of course, browser support.